# Initializing an external COM object causes w3wp.exe to crash with "Access Violation" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, com, w3wp

I'm trying to implement [Brother b-Pac printing library](https://www.brother.co.jp/eng/dev/bpac/index.aspx) for label printing devices into my web application. I need to create/load the label template on server and print from the client's machine over a browser.

My code is totally working on my development environment. It only occurs on the published version. It's an access denied error thrown when the COM object got called by the app. I suspect there's an inner exception I couldn't reach.

The event got logged as follows:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384
Faulting module name: bpac.dll, version: 3.2.0.20
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0010beea
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Brother\b-PAC\bpac.dll
```

I also used *DebugDiag* on the dump file and [here's the report](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TBMm0mCZHd5l9vKpnDrRC5NPEmGD1-F1). Though it says here debugger couldn't locate debug symbols for `bpac.dll`, so it may be incomplete (If it may help, I'd like to know where and how to get symbols for a 3rd party DLL)

Application is a multilayer *ASP.NET MVC* app targeting the *.NET Framework 4.6.1*, running on a virtual machine with *Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)* and *IIS 8*. (If it matters the project is derived from [this template](https://aspnetboilerplate.com))

I searched about the issue and tried the following solutions:

- Give read/write permissions of `wwwroot` and DLL's own folder to the `IIS APPPOOL/user` of the faulting `w3wp.exe`.
- Give same permissions to `IIS_IUSRS, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE` users.
- Impersonate `Administrator` user.
- Uninstall/install 32bit/64bit versions of the b-Pac SDK.
- Change bitness of my ASP app and all projects within to x86/x64.
- Enable 32bit on the Application Pool.
- Patch the Windows for [July 2018 update issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update)
- Setting *Anonymous Authentication, App pool identity etc.* all to the default pool user.
- Loading the DLL dynamically. (not sure if I did this correctly though)

The COM object I'm trying to initialize is `bpac.Document`. Interface is `IDocument` and the concrete class is  `DocumentClass`. I wasn't familiar with any of these concepts before. And I'm still struggling to understand but I tried all of these following lines for initialization:

```
Document label = new Document();
DocumentClass label = new DocumentClass(); //embed interop types: false
IDocument label = new Document();
```

After that, I'm using label object to open a template and etc. But as soon as the application hits any of the above lines it crashes the server and restarts the app.

Incidentally, the DLL file is referenced as a COM library in my WebService (App) project (not in the Web project). So it doesn't get copied on `bin` folder (I guess that's the correct behaviour?). Tried changing isolation/interop settings but I'm not sure if those are related to the issue at hand.

I read things about **Registering COM objects into GAC** and **Marshalling for Remote Access** but I couldn't grasp how to apply these properly. Thing is, the official documentation doesn't say anything about this. And there isn't a single example for using b-Pac library on a modern C# ASP.NET setting ([only a little on VB](http://download.brother.com/pub/com/dev/pdf/bpac_webapplication_eng.pdf) ~eww~).

I'm a developer, not a DBA so I'm not too confident with tweaking the server's settings. But for this issue alone, I modified too many things too many times.

Comment: "Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Brother\b-PAC\bpac.dll" is a red flag. Contact the vendor, and see if they support using this library in IIS (very likely no).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was about the app id permissions all along. I changed the Application Pool's identity to **LocalSystem** and now it works as expected.

Still, I'm not sure what kind of security flaws this change would cause in the future. I posted this link to the vendor's technical staff. But they didn't give me an answer yet.